# Pure JavaScript TagName and So forth

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I am still trying to learn pure javascript seeing as I skipped it and went to learn jQuery, though I don't want a library anymore. I want speed, anyways I have a few questions about pure JavaScript.

**First Question :**

```
var profile = document.getElementsByClassName("postprofile-details");
var details = profile.getElementsByTagName("dd");
    details[0].style.display = "none";
```

I keep getting an error of

```
TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'
```

How would I go about this?

**Next question** which is pertaining to the same code above basically, I know jQuery has a `.prepend()` and `.append()` so how would I insert additional HTML to the `var profile` above?

**Third and Last Question**

I would like to figure out this sort of issue, I've been learning the loop function instead of the `.each()` and this is what I have come up with but getting errors

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('postprofile-details');
   for (var i =0; i<a.length; i++) {
           a[i].getElementsByTagName('dd').style.display='none';
   }
```

Question at hand is how do I actually go about making sure I am selecting the loop inside the for loop function? Do I

**A**) a[i].getEle...

or

**B**) a.getEle...

Any answers to these questions would be helpful, I'm just tired of using jQuery

**With the Follow Answers and Comments**

Let me see if I can write this

```
var profile = document.getElementsByTagName('postprofile-details');
for (var i=0; i<profile.length; i++) {
  var dd = profile[i].getElementsByTagName('dd');
  dd.style.display='none';
  var newEle = document.createElement('div');
  newEle.id = 'toggle';
  profile[i].appendChild(newEle);
 }
```

Please let me know if any issue in my code are visible thank you.

Comment: I think not using a js library like jquery because of speed is really premature optimization. Just a note!

Comment: The "speed" difference between using jQuery and "plain" javascript is approximately non-existant.

Comment: three separate questions in three separate questions would make more sense than three in one. With three in one, it discourages anyone who may know the answer to one of the three from answering unless they can also answer the other two.

Comment: profile is a NodeList

Comment: Also note, `document.getElementsByClassName` isn't supported in IE8.

Comment: @TamasPap and @BradM You'd be surprised at the speed differences of the `.each()` function compared to the for loop ;) I saw it immediately look at the library and see the filthy code that lies within the .each() it itself has a for loop plus others which makes it nonsensical. The three questions technically all relate to each other one way or the way ;)

Comment: There's a big difference between `$.each` vs. native loops, and `$(".x .y")` vs. `var ys=document.getElementsByClassName("y"); for(i=0 ...`

Comment: Thank you @JanDvorak atleast someone agrees with me HAHA.

Comment: @EasyBB, the first and the third are the same issue, the second is not   related at all.

Comment: The first and the last question have the same answer: `getElement`*s*… always returns a **list of elements** you have to loop over (and you seem to know how to fix that, you do it in your second snippet).

Comment: @EasyBB my note is that while iteration performance could be noticable, element selection performance likely won't.

Comment: Ok everyone, let me see if I can write this, updating first post and let me know please. I don't want anyone to write me a code, as I am trying to focus on this myself. Any questions or fixes are appreciated!

Comment: what do you want to do for the first

Comment: I've updated my question. I am trying to hide the `<dd>` in the `.postprofile-details` then add an element `div`to it, so when they click that div it will make the `<dd>` visible.

Comment: @JanDvorak so maybe I could combine the two? Vanilla and jQuery?

Comment: @EasyBB of course you could. You shouldn't do math in jQuery (mainly due to readability concerns :-) ) and Vanilla.js excels at looping as well, but doing DOM manipulation in jQuery is perfectly fine. What hurts are reflows (and you can avoid them with jQuery just as well), not CPU instructions.

Comment: Lol, for being a newb I actually understood most of what you said. I barely do math in jQuery, never have I think that was the first bit of vanilla I learned actually. Anyways what do you mean by this "What hurts are reflows"

Comment: Also could you take a look at my rough code I added to see if I was getting the concept down? I didn't use jQuery though I probably will to make element selection easier.

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

You should use:

```
profile[index].getElementsByTagName("dd");
```

With the desired node, you can not use `getElementsByTagName` on  a node list.

> Next question which is pertaining to the same code above basically, I know jQuery has a .prepend() and .append() so how would I insert additional HTML to the var profile above?

```
profile[index].appendChild(newNode);
```

**Last answer:**

As the first answer, you need to iterate all the nodeList `getElementsByTagName`\ `getElementsByClassName` returns.

Comment: Would you please write some more on how to create a newNode?

Comment: @Sylvanus `document.createElement(tagName)`

Comment: Ok so it becomes a NodeList. Which technically I am still unaware of since I am still learning the javascript language, I could write the code, just the typeErrors are still getting to me. I am going to update my first post with what @gdoron has written and see if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: @gdordon Upvoted your Answer, and will probably check it as the best answer since no one else is posting answers lol. Thank you